# Using a CGColor

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

According to the apple documentation for CGColor:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/1455631-init

I should be able to create a CGColor with

```
CGColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
```

However, when I try to do this in XCode:

[image]

I am simply trying to create a function such that I can pass in a CGColor, and the CGColor parameter has a default value.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of that you read

`CGColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)`

is only in Mac OS. iOS doesn't support it

If you want to do the same in iOS, you can convert it from the `UIColor` by

```
UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
```